# <error-page> Как отправить пользователя на предыдущую страницу?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, servlet

я знаю что если в web.xml написать это:

```
<error-page>
        <location>/error.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

то выскочит при ошибке данная страница. Но а можно ли вместо конкретной страницы отправить пользователя на предыдущую?

я использую spring mvc

Comment: 1. Создать фильтр, обернуть `chain.doFilter()` в `try catch` и если будет ошибка, достать из `ServletRequest`, из заголовка страницу откуда пришел юзер. 2. Создать `ControllerAdvice` и достать заголовок из `HttpServletRequest` и сделать `response.sendRedirect()`. Но. первый вариант костыль. Второй более актуален. Но! второй (возможно и первый) вариант не сработает если на `jsp` странице возникла ошибка.